The named parameter 'onPressed' isn't defined
The name parameter 'on Pressed' isn't defined
I am trying to make an app with a sign in page but i can't make the button work

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({super.key});


  @override
  State<SignIn> createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {


  // ignore: unused_field
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  // text field state
  String email = '';
  String password = '';



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.brown[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: const Text('Sign in to LejweConnect'),

      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 50.0),
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              TextFormField(
                onChanged: (val){
                  setState(() => email = val);

                }
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  onChanged: (val){
                    setState(() => password = val);

                  }
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.pink[400],
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  child: Text(
                   'Sign in',
                  style: const  TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  
                  onPressed: () async {
                    
                  }

The named parameter 'onPressed' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'onPressed'.dartundefined_named_parameter
How do i fix this problem

Why are you trying to pass an onPressed parameter to a constructor that doesn't take such a parameter?

Please add the complete code.You need to provide a minimal reproducible example

You are passing onPressed to a container which doesn't accept onPressed as a parameter that's why you are getting onPressed error.
Only certain widgets accept onPressed parameters like buttons which you can use to do the press behaviour. Equivalently if you want to make the container clickable you can wrap it with InkWell and pass a the function to onTap. Eg:
InkWell(
  onTap: () {}, // paste your onPressed fn here
  child: Container(
    child: Text("test"),
  ),
)



Thank you so much that really helped.. the only problem is that my button doesn't seem like a button but it's clickable it doesn't have that button feel when you hover over it. Any thoughts on that?

If you want a button you can make use of the appropriate button itself, otherwise you would need to style the inkwell or the container just like a button. Also, please accept the answer if it helped you.

You can not use onpressed inside of a container. Wrap your Container with GestureDectector and use onTap.
